# Gaps and islands problem to get minimum for each partition, given date continuity of 1 day

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, gaps-and-islands

I have many records in the table. I was grouped by continuous date.

example :

| begin_at (From Date) | end_at (to date) |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-05 00:00:00 | 2023-06-18 00:00:00 |
| 2023-06-11 00:00:00 | 2023-06-18 00:00:00 |
| 2023-06-12 00:00:00 | 2023-06-18 00:00:00 |
| 2023-06-13 00:00:00 | 2023-06-18 00:00:00 |
| 2023-06-14 00:00:00 | 2023-06-18 00:00:00 |
| 2023-06-20 00:00:00 | 2023-06-18 00:00:00 |

Wanted [Final Result](https://prnt.sc/2Vltd5Fozi9Q):

| begin_at (From Date) | end_at (to date) |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-05 00:00:00 | 2023-06-18 00:00:00 |
| 2023-06-11 00:00:00 | 2023-06-18 00:00:00 |
| 2023-06-20 00:00:00 | 2023-06-18 00:00:00 |

I can use `GROUP BY end_at` and `ORDER BY begin_at`, although it would show continuous date but missing some data.

My coding attempt:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM period  p 
WHERE p.property_id = '218140' AND p.status<>'available' 
GROUP BY date(end_at) 
ORDER BY date(begin_at) ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

In the dbfiddle, I first create a column (It's the `CASE WHEN.... END` stuff), which has the value you need/want. then you can use that to select the appropriate data:

```
SELECT begin_at, end_at
FROM (
   SELECT
      CASE WHEN ADDDATE(lag(begin_at) over (order by begin_at), INTERVAL 1 DAY) <> begin_at OR ADDDATE(lag(begin_at) over (order by begin_at), INTERVAL 1 DAY) is null
        THEN begin_at END as begin_at,
      end_at
   FROM mytable
) x
WHERE not begin_at is null
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/bnJIs-4i)

Comment: Very smart solution indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `gaps and islands` problem, one option is to use the window functions to solve it :

First, the `cte` function was used to return the date difference between the previous and current row, as well as the date difference between the next and current row, using the `lag()` and `lead()` functions.

To determine if we have successive dates, `cte2` was used to check if the date difference between the current and previous or next row is one day.

`cte3` was used to define the groups using the approach of two `row_number()` :

```
with cte as (
  select *, datediff(day, lag(begin_at) over (order by begin_at), begin_at) as date_diff_lag,
                   datediff(day, begin_at, lead(begin_at) over (order by begin_at)) as date_diff_lead
  from period
),
cte2 as (
  select *, case when date_diff_lag = 1 or date_diff_lead = 1 then 1 else date_diff_lag end as date_diff
  from cte
),
cte3 as (
  select *, row_number() over (order by begin_at) - row_number() over (partition by date_diff order by begin_at) as grp
  from cte2
)

select min(begin_at) as begin_at , max(end_at) as end_at
from cte3
group by grp
```

Result :

| begin_at | end_at |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-05 | 2023-06-18 |
| 2023-06-11 | 2023-06-18 |
| 2023-06-20 | 2023-06-18 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/fE1BWXyA)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using legacy versions of MySQL, you can approach this problem with variables:

- variable "*@begin_at*", to check when there's a difference between consecutive begin days
- variable "*@end_at*", to check when there's a difference between consecutive end_days
- variable "*@partition*", that will store partition values

```
SET @begin_at := CAST(NULL AS DATE);
SET @end_at := CAST(NULL AS DATE);
SET @partition := 0;

SELECT MIN(begin_at) AS begin_at, 
       end_at
FROM (SELECT IF(@begin_at = ADDDATE(begin_at, INTERVAL -1 DAY) AND @end_at = end_at, 
                @partition, 
                @partition := @partition+1) AS parts,
             @begin_at := begin_at          AS begin_at,
             IF(@end_at = end_at, 
                @end_at, 
                @end_at := end_at)          AS end_at
     FROM tab
     ORDER BY begin_at) cte
GROUP BY end_at, parts
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9GTnDcUk5EjsaC32VbAvoX/1).